# save registration in text file (notepad) not in database java swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fd0172/registration-form-in-windows-form-using-swing-in-java/) is a link for saving registration in database using java swing i want to know to register the same thing but not in database but in a text file for example in note pad?any link is appreciated

Comment: Simple just save the detail into the File which you are getting from user.

Comment: Guess you could use one more more XML files to save the registration. But I don't really know where your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your registration details in csv file. And get them back. 
Check out [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-export-data-to-csv-file-java/)! Also [Check this](http://www.journaldev.com/2544/java-csv-parserwriter-example-using-opencsv-apache-commons-csv-and-supercsv)!

Comment: This should be comment not answer.

Comment: I cant comment, since my points are less than 50. And HogRider asked for a link and thats why added there.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code is for creating file and saving text in it .

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("Hello.txt",true);
  PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(fout,true);
  pr.println("hello");
```